# Ruby limit types of class passed to a method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

What i stumbled upon just now - how to **easily** limit verity  of classes that are passed to one method to only one class type ? ex. code:

```
class S
  attr_reader :s
  def initialize(s = nil)
    @s = s || 14
  end
end

class Gets
  def self.read(s)
    s.s
  end

end

s=S.new
p Gets.read(s) # 14
```

Let's say that class S has a more complex structure and i want to be sure that only that class could be passed to `Gets#read` method, **how can i do that?**

Comment: Check the class? But what's the purpose? That limits how you can use the method. IMO at most check that it implements what you actually care about, its interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While to solution of [sawa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16188839/273395) definitely is valid and does exactly what you want. In dynamic languages like ruby it's actually more common to use [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

The idea is to just assert to which messages the attribute must respond to. This allows to easily pass in e.g. a different implementation.

```
class Gets
  def self.read(obj)
    raise ArgumentError, "must implement #s" unless obj.respond_to?(:s)
    obj.s
  end
end
```

Comment: Actually, this is what the Ruby community calls "chicken typing", because you are afraid of someone passing in the wrong kind of object.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Gets
  def self.read(s)
    raise ArgumentError unless s.kind_of?(S)
    s.s
  end
end
```